# How to obtain instance of Instrumentation in Java

Tags: java, memory, instrumentation

I am trying to write a simply `ObjectUtils` class that contains a variety of utility methods for all Objects. I would like to have one of them called `getObjectSize(Object)` where you pass it an instantiated Object and it returns the Object's size in memory:

```
public class ObjectUtils {
    private static volatile Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static final long getObjectSize(final Object p_oToGauge)
    {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(p_oToGauge);
    }
}
```

However, it seems that in order to obtain an implemented `Instrumentation` instance, you need to do all sorts of fancy things with JRE agents and a so-called `premain` method.

Is there an easy way to get access to the local JRE's `Instrumentation` instances?  I looked for something through the `Runtime` API but could find nothing.

Comment: I _think_ there isn't.  You're going to have to do the fancy stuff.

Comment: I dug out this post from Alex Snaps that you might find useful: http://www.codespot.net/blog/2012/01/measuring-java-object-sizes/

Answer (score 2):

I found a class called [`InstrumentationFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa-all/2.3.0/org/apache/openjpa/enhance/InstrumentationFactory.java).

The first time someone asks for an instance of `Instrumentation`, it creates an agent JAR file, then finds the PID of its own process and attaches it to the JVM inside that... Which calls its `agentmain(..)`, giving it the `Instrumentation` instance of interest.

I'm not sure how reliable that approach is. What I would try next is search the code of OpenJDK to see where and how an `Instrumentation` instance is created. Perhaps, in the absence of security requirements, it would be possible (via reflection) to get that mechanism to furnish an `Instrumentation` instance without having to attach or preload an agent?