# how to redefine class before bean initialize in spring project

Tags: java, jvm-bytecode

I hava A Class in another jar and i use it in B bean.
Now i want to add log for method in A Class. How can i do this in my project without fix the jar.

My mind:

1. use ApplicationListener to redefine class before bean init.
2. do something in onApplicationEvent() to redefine the A class.  // this is my question.

I know that can use asm or other tool to fix bytecode. I hava see instrument and do not find solution . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

[How to obtain instance of Instrumentation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692357/how-to-obtain-instance-of-instrumentation-in-java)

A class.

```
public class A {

public void find(){
    System.out.println("aaa");
    //i want to add log here.
}
```

B bean

```
@Service public class B { 
public A get(){
    return new A();
}
```

ApplicationListener

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    if(event.getApplicationContext().getParent() != null){
        return;
    }
   // redefine class
}
```

then when i use b.get().find()  it will print the log i add.

Answer (score 0):

find my solution.
using javassist modify the class. and load it （using CtClass.toClass()）in advance． 
https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html